# How to make unavailable to click some dates in qooxdoo date widget?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, qooxdoo, datefield

Is it possible to make specific dates or a range of dates in `qx.ui.form.DateField` widget unavailable to click/interact with somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality was added by me to qooxdoo version 7.2.1. You can set minimal and maximal dates via special properties like **MinValue** and **MaxValue**.